# How to show the full options list instead of a scroll view on google sidebar select multiple options

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

I have a 'select' form item on a google sidebar form. Without the multiple select it shows the full list in the default format ( like a validation bubble ). When I change it to multiple select the view changes to a fixed size with a scroll bar. Is there a way to keep the original presentation format.

Comment: I think just don't use the multiple attribute

Comment: I may end up doing just that. full display creates other complications like hiding the other form elements unless if there is a way to move the display to one side